# Connecting problem with react-native axios to database

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, axios, redux-saga

I am new in react-native, this is my first app. I think I have some communication problem to login from my phone to php myadmin. When I test my app from postman, everything works, but when I try to login from my app i have error

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'error.response.data')
* api.js:29:30 in <unknown>
- node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:37:14 in tryCallOne
- node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:123:25 in <unknown>
- ... 8 more stack frames from framework internals

The above error occurred in task loginUser
    created by takeEvery(LOGIN_REQUEST, loginUser)
    created by rootSaga
    created by rootSaga
Tasks cancelled due to error:
takeEvery(LOGIN_REQUEST, loginUser)
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\YellowBox\YellowBox.js:59:8 in error
- node_modules\expo\build\environment\muteWarnings.fx.js:27:24 in error
- ... 30 more stack frames from framework internals
```

i am using axios, redux and redux-saga...
my api call for this is:

```
export function login_api(user) {
    return axios.post('http://api.popis.test/api/auth/login', {
        username: user.username,
        password: user.password
    }).catch((error) => {
        if(error.response && error.response.data && error.response.data.error){
            return error.response.data.error;
        }
        return error.response.data;
    })
}
```

i read a lot of posts on stackoverflow, and someone wrote that problem can be in https and suggested to use ip address... When I changed my api to call ip address, nothing happens...post request stays in login_request. My api call for this is:

```
const uri = `http://${manifest.debuggerHost.split(':').shift()}:4000`;

export function login_api(user) {
    return axios.post(uri+'/api/auth/login', user)
}
```

my saga is:

```
export function* loginUser(action) {
    const response = yield call(login_api, action.payload)
    if(!response || !response.data) {
        return yield put(login_failure('Internal server error for login user'))
    }
    if(response.status === 200) {
        return yield put(login_success(response.data))
    } else {
        return yield put(login_failure('Error for login user'))
    }
}
```

Reducer is:

```
const initialState = {
    user : [],
    error: []
}

export default function loignReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case constants.LOGIN_REQUEST:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true
            }
        case constants.LOGIN_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                user: action.payload
            }
        case constants.LOGIN_FAILURE:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                error: action.payload
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Can someone help me? If you need more code, please make me know?

Comment: set a breakpoint in the first line of the catch block. The error sounds to me that that the if condition cannot be because "error.response" is undefined.

Comment: i tried, response is undefined whatever i write in login page.. Success, and wrong login gave me a same error from saga         return yield put(login_failure('Internal server error for login user'))

Comment: sorry, what i meant is, just output "error" (i.e. console.log(error); ) before the if and see what that spits out. Or try to connect with postman to the backend service to check it is working properly